# How to make xlock use the first key I hit as a part of my password

Tags: 10.10, screensaver, lock-screen, unlock

I just switched from Arch Linux to Ubuntu 10.10. I'm running the Fluxbox window manager, and I use xlockmore to lock my screen with the following key shortcut:

```
192   :Exec xlock-mode marquee +usefirst -icongeometry 240x240 -message "back in a minute..."
```

The problem I'm having is that xlock is definitely *not* using my first key as part of my password. Instead, it uses some randomized fade pattern to fade to the password screen.  I find this highly annoying, as when I get back to my desk and start entering my password it doesn't register password characters until the fade pattern is complete.

I've also tried the following modifications with no difference:

```
192 :Exec xlock -mode marquee -usefirst -icongeometry 240x240 -message "back in a minute..."

192 :Exec xlock -mode marquee -icongeometry 240x240 -message "back in a minute..."
```

The first example worked flawlessly on Arch. Does Ubuntu have some sort of system default that you can't override on the command-line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tried both your first example (the one with `+usefirst`) and the second one (the one with `-usefirst`); the first one didn't use the first key, but the second one did. This is in 11.04, which has version 1:5.31-1, so maybe it's that; just in case, I dumped it into my junk ppa (`ppa:chipaca/junk`) and it's building for maverick right now.

Comment: Let me know if that works out. I'm not averse to building from source. And I didn't check versions or anything, but it's highly likely that the version I got from Arch was newer than what 10.10 is using...

Comment: @alesplin the .deb built, so please go ahead and test it on Maverick. If you'd rather not add the ppa, [download the packages manually](https://launchpad.net/~chipaca/+archive/junk/+packages).

Comment: thanks. I'll install it first thing when I get to work on Monday.